# Can a laptop connect to an ethernet network printer with WIFI?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printer, ethernet

I was asked to find a solution to following problem:

A home network has different laptops and printers, all connected in an ethernet network. A WIFI router was connected to the network. Now a user with a laptop without ethernet connection but with WIFI would like to print on a network printer.

The problem is that the network printers do not have WIFI. The only possible connection would be

> ```
>        ethernet           WIFI
> ```
>
> printer <------------- WIFI router <----- laptop

Is this connection possible?

Comment: Broadly speaking, the answer is _most likely yes_. However, if you're having difficulty with this set up, edit the question to include the exact models of laptops, printers, and routers.

Comment: Yes this is fine.  If your printer and the laptop both exist on the same network and get IP addresses on the same subnet it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problem. If you connect the printer to the router with a network cable, it will get an IP address from the router. You can then use that IP address to connect to the printer.

Once the printer is plugged in, print a configuration page so you'll know its IP address. Then try pinging it from the laptop by typing (from a DOS prompt)

> PING IP_Address_of_Printer

If you see replies from the printer, you are ready to install it. If PING times out, compare the IP address of the printer with that of the laptop. If they are not on the same subnet (i.e. the first 3 numbers of the address are the same on both) then change settings on the router so it will connect the two subnets.

Before installing the driver, you should give the printer a fixed IP address, either by reserving it on the router, or by manually setting it on the printer. In the latter case, make sure it is outside the DHCP range of the router - other wise you might get duplicate addresses at some time in the future. If you install the driver first and change the IP later, then go to Printer Properties > Ports > Configure Port and change the address there to match that of the printer.

Answer (score 2):

If your printer is connected to network by ethernet and your laptop is connected to network by WifI you sould be able to [PING](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737478%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) your printer's IP Address.  If it's the case, then you just have to install printer's driver and it will work.